# C# How can I acces the same variable in mutliple classes

Tags: c#

I'm working on my third C# program and I'm having a hard time.
I don't get how I can access a variable in multiple classes :

This is a slider to control the size of the shape I'm drawing

```
    public void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int slider = (int)trackBar1.Value ;

    }




    public void DrawCar ()
    {
        drawArea = drawingArea.CreateGraphics();
        Pen blackpen = new Pen(Color.Orange);
        drawArea.DrawLine(blackpen, slider , 10, 500, 500);
        drawArea.DrawArc(Pens.Orange, new Rectangle( 10 , 10, 100, 100), 50, 100);
    }
```

I need to access the "slider" value to control the size of the car.

Comment: Make it global ,Class variable

Comment: Wrap it into a public property.

Comment: Do you actually have the code in multiple classes, or are those methods in the same class?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access it in the same class, but multiple methods, you can make that as a member variable of the class.

```
public class YourClass
{
  private int sliderValue=0;
  public void MethodA()
  {
   sliderValue=12;
  }
  public void MethodB()
  {
    var localValue=sliderValue+10;
  }
}
```

If you want the value across multiple classes, you might consider creating a [singleton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) class and add the properties you want to that.

Answer (score 0):

Add a property to your class that contains trackBar1 like this:

```
public int Slider { get { return this.trackBar1.Value; } }
```

Then you can access the slider value outside on the class where the trackBar1 is defined from instances of that class.

Comment: If I wanted to use the variable in say 200 classes (for a  game or something) would I have to add this to the properties of each class?

Comment: @Wagacca That depends.  I would need to see more of your code to make that determination.  But I would say that if you have that variable in 200 classes, then hopefully those 200 classes are inheriting from a base class.  Please post more of your work so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

the best thing you can achieve to get access is this way or start using mvvm pattern and defining properties, that will make things lot easier:

```
   public static int slider;  

    public void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          slider  = (int)trackBar1.Value ;
        }
        public void DrawCar ()
        {
            drawArea = drawingArea.CreateGraphics();
            Pen blackpen = new Pen(Color.Orange);
            drawArea.DrawLine(blackpen, slider , 10, 500, 500);
            drawArea.DrawArc(Pens.Orange, new Rectangle( 10 , 10, 100, 100), 50, 100);
        }
```